# First click handler removes element and second handler doesn't run, how can I run both?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm using a jQuery plugin (leaflet.js) that has popups. I want to do some stuff when the close button is clicked, but since I'm not the one creating the close button, I have to attach a handler with `jQuery.on()` like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.leaflet-popup-close-button', function () {
    // do stuff
}
```

This works for other events (such as `mouseover`), but because it's a close button I'm clicking, the element disappears the instant it's clicked, and my handler isn't run.

How can I make my handler ALSO run (I don't want to remove the handler that's already there)?

**edit**

I can't use the built-in `popupclose` event because that event also fires if the popup is closed some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with leaflet, but I think you need to set the `closeButton` option to false, edit the DOM of the popup with your own close button, and have the callback for the click event call `togglePopup` or `closePopup` after whatever other code you want.

Comment: How do you suggest listening for new popups? Meaning, when a new popup is created, how do I know that it's there and that I should edit the DOM?

Comment: Looks like there's an `add` event for all markers. In your listener, you can probably determine the type and run your code if it's a popup.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense - I'll give it a try and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest listening for a close event from the leaflet.js and use that to trigger your action: 
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup